# Does Mailgun API provide smtp responses?

Tags: mailgun

Can't find that in the documentation. SES provides these logs like `250 Ok: queued as 1CB8B220198`. Does Mailgun provide logs like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Api has response like 'queued .... messageId'.
and i also think smtp calls also response as queued ... messageId

and you also login the contol panel > Logs section you can see the logs what is happened.